# Recursive set or not

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, computation-theory, turing-machines

I'm trying to solve a problem from the university, but I have no idea how to solve it. can someone possibly help me and say how can I prove that the two under mentioned languages are decidable or undecidable

L1:= M, w | On input w, the Turing machine M never moves the read/write head to the left, where w ∈ {0, 1} ∗ and M ∈ {0, 1} ∗.

L2:= M, w | On input w, the Turing machine M moves the read/write head in every step, where w ∈ {0, 1} ∗ and M ∈ {0, 1} ∗.

Comment: Hint: for each restriction on M, what class of languages can machines that follow that restriction recognize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L1: Let M begin processing w. If it moves the read/write head left, you can halt-reject immediately since we know the answer. Otherwise, it will eventually read the entire finite input and break into the blank spaces to the right of the input, after which all tape cells are blank. Now, continue allowing the TM to run. If it moves the read/write head left, again, halt-reject. Otherwise, all we need to do is detect the moment when the TM first enters the same state twice. Why is that? If the TM enters some state twice after reading all input and already being in the blank spaces to the right of the input, the TM has entered a closed cycle and will continue transitions between the states in the cycle while moving the tape head to the right forever. By the pigeonhole principle, you only need to check as many transitions as there are states of the TM before you are guaranteed to halt, move left or repeat a state. Of course, if the TM transitions to halt-accept or halt-reject at any point before moving the read/write head to the left, you have your answer as well. This means this problem is decidable.

L2: Let M' be any TM for which we'd like to solve the halting problem. For each state Q in M' we can add a new state Q' whose sole function is to replace transitions in M' that did not move the read/write head with transitions from Q to Q' and back again, so that M'' has twice as many states as M' and no transitions that keep the read/write head stationary. Now, we can change all transitions to either halt-accept or halt-reject so that they keep the tape head stationary (no reason not to); call this M'''. The TM M''' has the property that it accepts exactly what M' accepts, rejects exactly what M' rejects, loops forever where M' loops forever, and contains transitions that keep the read/write head stationary only when it explicitly halts on an input. Now, suppose our problem were decidable; that is, we can decide whether an arbitrary TM ever keeps the tape head stationary while processing some input w. Then we could decide whether M''' ever keeps the tape head stationary while processing w. But, since M''' has been constructed in such a way that the tape head is only ever stationary when the TM is halting, this tells us that M''' halts (or not) on w. This allows us to decide the halting problem for our arbitrary TM M'. This is an absured conclusion, so our problem cannot be decidable.